# How to display Grafana dashboard of commands issued per time interval

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am incrementing a counter each time a command is started and an entry is added to influx every few milliseconds for the current value of the counter, producing entries like below.

```
time            value
----            -----
1549754123986   0
1549754183993   1
1549754243999   2
1549754304005   3
```

I would like to have a Grafana time sequence dashboard that displays how many times the command has been started over a time interval (e.g. per hour, per 3 hours, per 6 hours, ...).

For example if commands are started at 9:00, 9:30, 10:45, 11:00 and 12:15, then the graph of commands started per hour would look something like:

```
3|
2|       -------                 -----------
1|-------       --------    -----           -----    ----------------
0|_________________________________________________________________________
  9:00  9:30  10:00   10:30   11:00   11:30   12:00    12:30   1:00
```

From the influx functions listed on https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/functions, I would like to do a difference between max values at 1 hour apart (and 3, 6, 12, 24 hours apart for the other intervals).

What would my select statement look like?

Thanks to brunorey who answered below, before I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM()` with `GROUP BY` to select the total amount of times the value has been 1 over periods of three hours:

```
> SELECT SUM(value) FROM my_data GROUP BY time(3h);
name: my_data
time                 sum
----                 ---
2019-02-06T12:00:00Z 216
2019-02-06T15:00:00Z 766
2019-02-06T18:00:00Z 704
2019-02-06T21:00:00Z 547
2019-02-07T00:00:00Z 436
2019-02-07T03:00:00Z 497
>
```

From your data I understand that `value` is always either `1` or `0`.

If there are more different numbers and you want to get every time it has been 1, you can use a COUNT with a condition:

```
> SELECT COUNT(value) FROM my_data WHERE value=1 GROUP BY time(3h);
```

The queries above are good for influx, if you want to implement them in grafana I suggest you either define an interval variable (see [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/#interval-variables)) or use the `$__interval` variable (see [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/#the-interval-variable)) which will adjust automatically according to your zoom level:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM my_data GROUP BY time($__interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

For counts per hour: SELECT non_negative_derivative(last("value"), 1h) FROM "counter" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1h) fill(null)